# index.php лежит не в корне сайта и сайт не грузится

Tags: php

Возникла проблема с загрузкой сайта. Структура такова, что файл index.php лежит не в корне, а в папке web. Там же лежат стили, скрипты, картинки и т.д. Есть и другие src, vendor.
  Так вот как сделать так, чтобы сайт грузился из web, а то он грузится только таким образом site.com/web.
Нашел способ прописать в .htaccess такие строки:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine on
     RewriteRule   ^$ web/    [L]
     RewriteRule   ((?s).*) web/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Но тогда происходит ошибка сервера Internal Server Error. 
Еще пытался поменять в "www-домены" значение "индексная страница" на "web/index.php", но тогда почему то не грузятся стили. В source показано, что пути к файлами css такие site.com/style.css, а не site.com/web/style.css. 
Может есть еще какие-то настройки в isp manager. Я что-то не могу найти. До этого сайт лежал на другом хостинге у другого владельца, у которого я уже не могу спросить как это работает.

Структура примерно такая:

```
  /www/site.ru/ 
      -src 
      -vendor
      -web
          --index.php
```

Comment: Так никто не делает - есть одна точка входа - это корень директории. От него дальше строится роутинг страниц и т.д.

Comment: @And расскажите это разрабам Laravel, Symfony, плюс всяких CMS, у многих входная точка лежит не в корне)

Comment: @СашаБоричевский тут ничего не говорится про CMS и всяких мусорных фреймворках. Я лишь подметил, что нормальный, так не сделает. Да и вообще, какой смысл делать вложенный корневой каталог? Бессмысленно. Ладно вы хостер, а так - это делать не имеет смысла.

Comment: @And например для безопасности

Comment: @Peresada, чуш полнейшая! О какой безопасности идет речь?

Comment: @And да все просто, можно прописывать бесконечные правила в htaccess, в каждую папку добавлять свой htaccess, а можно просто все директории, которые должен "видеть" только сам сервер вынести на уровень выше public_html, тоже самое касается пользовательских файлов, которые никогда не должны отображаться в интернете, а что если они имеют динамические расширения? Все заранее предусмотреть в htaccess не всегда получится. Поэтому большинство фреймворков (кстати это достаточно забавно слышать "мусорный фреймворк" к symphony, laravel и прочее) используют свою папку для вывода

Comment: бгг, меня тоже "мусорные фреймворки" повеселили :D cakephp если брать, то там индекс тоже не в корне.

Comment: уберите вы `(?s)` свое непонятное  из правила, просто `(.*)  web/$1` и все. Все что приходит на вход перенаправляется в web и все.

Comment: хотя вообще `(?s)` не должно мешать никак

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш нужно настроить виртуальный хост вашего сервера на папку "web".
Подробнее можно узнать в [документации](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/ru/vhosts/)

```html
<VirtualHost адрес_хоста_для прослушивания:порт>
ServerName домен
ServerAlias псевдоним_домена
ServerAdmin емейл@администратора
DocumentRoot /путь/к/файлам/сайта
ErrorLog /куда/сохранять/логи/ошибок/error.log
CustomLog /куда/сохранять/логи/доступа/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Давайте сначала определимся с терминами: Корень - это самая верхняя директория, куда Вам позволяет добраться хостинг. Точка входа - это папка, которая видна всему интернету (чаще всего public_html). В данном случае, если в папке public_html и находится ваша директория web, то Вам нужно все содержимое public_html перекинуть в корень, а дальше следовать указаниям

1. Удалите дефолтную папку, по которой должен быть доступен Ваш сайт
   (чаще всего это public_html)
2. Зайдите в веб-версию консоли Вашего хостинга через панель управления и пропишите (замените имя_дирректории на соответствующий путь)

   ln -s ~/имя_директории/web ~/имя_директории/public_html
3. Если в панели управления нет веб-консоли, то подключитесь по SSH и
   выполните ту же команду

Эта команда создает символьную ссылку (по сути ярлык), которые делает перенаправление на нужную папку.

Иными словами, если в корне сайта (это там, где вы оказывается при подключении по SSH) у вас есть папки:

```
-dat
-log
-error
-public_html
-somedir
--web
```

То команда `ln -s ~/somedir/web ~/public_html` решит Вашу проблему

А из .htaccess можете удалить эти строки, если у Вас нет конкретной рекомендации Вашего хостинга.

Answer (score 0):

Здраствуйте ) можно решить вашу проблему с одним простым способом. Создайте в корневой директории файл `.htaccess` и пишите следующее в файле:

```
DirectoryIndex web/
```

и все. Все сработает